# Can Mathematica be used as a proof assistant?

Tags: theorem-proving, external-language-cell

Mathematica have an extensive gallery of mathematical results, as well as a strong rule-based deduction system. Since v12.*, automated proving features have been added to it too.
I believe for mathematicians, Mathematica have always been a useful tool for validating guesses, but I wonder if is it possible to use Mathematica in the proving phase. Thus I want to ask:

- Is Mathematica now a strong enough machine prover?
- Is it possible to integrate it with SOTA prove assistants, e.g. [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/)?

Comment: "strong enough" is definitely opinion-based. I'm not sure that this question is appropriate for this forum, unfortunately. Perhaps you could make it appropriate by asking "strong enough to prove <your example here>", and provide an actual example of integration you want to attempt.

Comment: @MarcoB -- Would some form of the following clarify what the OP needs and make it less opinion based?  e.g.,  "What can Mma's proving features do?  What limits do they have?  Where do they leave things in question"

Comment: @Jagra - I believe that would still be too broad. Good questions should be specific and be answerable with relatively short answers that don't require the responder to guess at examples that may or may not address the OP's intent/concerns and that may then lead to back and forth clarification.

Comment: @MacroBI think my OP is very bias-prone as you have pointed out. As I see it now, it may be a valid post for sites like Quora, but is too broad for MMA SE. But I do have broad questions myself (including those suggested by [@Jarga](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/571/jagra), which I prepare to research on by myself after raising this post), and I hope to discuss how to clarify them.

Comment: I'll put my immature ideas in comments, and update the content of the question only when appropriate. Is the user community of MMA familiar with [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) or similar tools (either generally, or specific members)? When WRI developed the current proving framework, do they aim to make built-ins like `Solve` `Minimize` more powerful, or do they expect users to prove theorems in their publications?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am not even sure if the [proving](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TheoremProving.html) functionality is a counterpart of Coq... I hope someone may point it out if I'm just confused about this. However, I do think this post is most relevant to MMA SE (after some clarification of course), rather than Quora, SO or even meta MMA SE. There is also *a* related [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/198525) on Wolfram community.

Comment: I am so sad that this question didn't get any answers. As a MMa user I looked at a prover like Lean, which is so incredibly immature that they have the guts to say that Lean 4 ( their next big thing ) is incompatible with previous versions. Also they moved from a prover to a functional language. But they are very good at creating HYPE, lots of it. I suppose they learned that from their paying masters MSFT. - But... I need a system to store proofs. And possibly work with them. Why not Mathematica?

Comment: @niloderoock I looked into LEAN a while ago too, and didn't go very deep; guess the main corpus of formalized mathametical knowledge is still only available in Coq to the day. To me, the confusing part is that this doesn't seem to be in the roadmap of Wolfram, Inc. while it claims to be *the* computation&knowledge company.

Comment: I am sure that Lean is still too much of an infant. Read https://jiggerwit.wordpress.com/2018/09/18/a-review-of-the-lean-theorem-prover/ - I am confident that Wolfram will take it up when the field becomes mature. - I will have a look at Coq though.